# Start simulations after each other from command line

Tags: scala, gatling

I’ve several simulations and I start simulation from command line in Windows like:

```
gatling.bat -s MySimulation1
```

But how do I pass more simulations so MySimulation1 is executed first and then MySimulation2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gatling.bat -s MySimulation1 && gatling.bat -s MySimulation2
```